# Spring integartion LoggingHandler logs all messages to Error

Tags: spring-boot, logging, spring-integration

I created a spring boot application that sends [Message](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/Message.html)s through a [PublishSubscribeChannel](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/channel/PublishSubscribeChannel.html). This Channel is "autowired" as SubscribableChannel interface.
I am only subscribing one MessageHandler to this channel, a [KafkaProducerMessageHandler](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-integration-kafka/1.2.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/integration/kafka/outbound/KafkaProducerMessageHandler.html).

My problem is that one additional MessageHandler is subscribed and this is an [LoggingHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/handler/LoggingHandler.html). It is instantiated with `ERROR` level. So i see every message logged es error.

I want to know why and where this LoggingHandler is wired (instantiated) and why it is subscribed to the channel - i want to disable it.

(
I debugged around a bit but (was not really helpful):
The LoggingHandler is instantiated and subscribed after the KafkaHandler.
I see this chain `EventdrivenConsumer.doStart()`<-- ``ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean.initializeEndpoint()<-- ... until reflective calls
)

**EDIT**

As suggested in comments here is some code (i can't share the whole project). My problem is that the code can't explain the behavior. The LoggingHandler is beeing subscribed to my PublishSubscribeChannel for some unknown reason and it is instantiated with error as level for some unknown reason.

The class that subscribes the KafkaHandler:

```
@Component
public class EventRelay  {

    @Autowired
    private EventRelay( SubscribableChannel eventBus, @Qualifier( KafkaProducerConfig.KAFKA_PRODUCER ) MessageHandler kafka ) {

        eventBus.subscribe( kafka );

    }
}
```

The class that send events is implementing an proprietary interface with many callback methods:

```
public class PropEvents implements PropClass.IEvents {

    private SubscribableChannel eventBus;
    private final ObjectMapper om;
    private final String userId;


    public PropEvents( SubscribableChannel eventBus, ObjectMapper om, String userId ) {

        this.eventBus = eventBus;
        this.om = om;
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLogin(  ) {
                 eventBus.send( new OnLoginMessage(... ) ) );
    } 
    //many other onXYZ methods
}
```

Here is the Factory that produces instances of PropEvents:

```
@Configuration
public class EventHandlerFactory {

    private final ObjectMapper om;
    private final SubscribableChannel eventBus;

    @Autowired
    public EventHandlerFactory( ObjectMapper om, SubscribableChannel eventBus){
        this.om = checkNotNull( om );
        this.eventBus = checkNotNull( eventBus );
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope( SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public IEvents getEvantHandler(String userId){
        if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(userId)){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "user id must be set." );
        }
        return new PropEvents(eventBus, om, userId);
    }

}
```

I appreciate any help with debugging or use tooling (e.g. Eclipse Spring tools does not show any hint to a LoggingHandler Bean) to find where and why a LoggingHandler is instantiated and subscribed to my autowired Channel.

My current workaround is to disable logging for LoggingHandler.

**My question at a glance**
Why spring instantiates an LoggingHandler with error level and subscribes it to my SubscribableChannel(provided by PublishSubscribeChannel)? How to disable this?

Comment: Why don't show a configuration or even share a small Spring Boot project to let us to reproduce it from our side? Right, now only one possible idea is like you are subscribing to the global `errorChannel`, which is really a `PublishSubscribeChannel` by default and has `LoggingHandler` as a default subscriber. Otherwise your question isn't clear and we are going to spend a lot of time asking each other additional questions. Thanks for understanding

Comment: Why don't you comment here that you have added some code to the question? We don't get notifications automatically.

Comment: What is that `eventBus` bean? Who and how creates and configures it? What is it really a problem to code a simple Spring Boot app to let us to play with the issue?

Comment: @Artem at start i told what this is: It is auto configured an instantiated by Spring. It automatically uses "PublishSubscribeChannel"

Comment: No, you didn’t. Auto wired and auto created are different stories, but now I definitely understand that the story is about a specific channel- `errorChannel`. And from here I see that you don’t know Spring Integration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-special-channels

Comment: because of that i asked the question here. i read it but i don't know why every message i send is also send as error to LoggingHandler. Could you probably create an answer?

Comment: Right, but you weren’t clear what is the channel you use. I’ll answer to you later today anyway

Comment: My Code only depends(by imports) on  "SubscribableChannel" interface (spring wires this to PublishSubscribeChannel). No other channels in any of my classes.

Comment: Right, if no any bean definitions, that is indeed a global `errorChannel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `@Autowired SubscribableChannel`, there should be one in the application context. That might be confusing a bit and mislead, but Spring Integration provides a `PublishSubscribeChannel` for the global `errorChannel`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-special-channels

This one has a `LoggingHandler` to log error as a default subscriber.

I don't think that it is OK to make your logic based on the `errorChannel`.

You should consider to declare your own `MessageChannel` bean and inject it by the particular `@Qualifier`.

Comment: Thanks - this also explains why autowiring SubscribableChannel works without declaring a bean.